# R: formating a dataframe in two specific ways based on separation and matching

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1 like this:

```
    A                 B
1 xxx      B2341; A3456
2 yyy B2341; CC6x; GG63
3 zzz              CC6X
4 www              GG63
5 kkk              5634
```

To obtain df1, I use the following commands

```
 df1 <- data.frame(A=c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "www", "kkk"), B=c("B2341; A3456", "B2341; CC6x; GG63", "CC6X", "GG63", "5634"))
```

In step one, I want to separate all the items (separated by ; and a space) in column B to table like this.  As I want to do some analysis based on this table format.  However, since there are uneven items for each cells.  I would like to ask fo your help to get it done.

```
xxx B2341
xxx A3456
yyy B2341
yyy CC6X
yyy GG63
zzz CC6X
www GG63
kkk 5634
```

In step two, I want to get a table based on the matching result of 2nd column of df2, i.e. both xxx and yyy got B2341 in 2nd column of df2.  yyy and zzz also got CC6X; yyy and www also got GG63.

So, I would like to have a df with two columns that show matching rows, such as:

```
xxx yyy
yyy zzz
yyy www
```

Please kindly help to instruct how to get the two dataframes based on my df1 with R in a smarter way.  Thank you.

Comment: Is `CC6x` where x is lower case, supposed to be the same as `CC6X`?

Answer (score 6):

Step One:

```
library(reshape)
x <- melt((strsplit(as.character(df1$B), "; ")))
x <- data.frame("A"=df1[x$L1,1],"B"=x$value)
```

x:

```
  value L1 match
1 B2341  1   xxx
2 A3456  1   xxx
3 B2341  2   yyy
4  CC6x  2   yyy
5  GG63  2   yyy
6  CC6X  3   zzz
7  GG63  4   www
8  5634  5   kkk
```

Step 2:

```
y <- unique(merge(x,x[duplicated(x$B),],by="B")[2:3])
y[y$A.x != y$A.y,]
```

y:

```
  A.x A.y
1 xxx yyy
3 yyy www
```

Note: step 2 doesn't come out exactly as you specified because I believe you mistyped "CC6X" as "CC6x", if you wanted it to ignore capitalization I would recommend  `x$B <- tolower(x$B)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the `foreach` package. I use it in some way for everything I write in R.

```
library(foreach)
foreach(a=df1$A, b=as.character(df1$B), .combine=rbind) %do% {
    data.frame(A=a, B=strsplit(b, "; ")[[1]])
}
```

Output:

```
    A     B
1 xxx B2341
2 xxx A3456
3 yyy B2341
4 yyy  CC6x
5 yyy  GG63
6 zzz  CC6X
7 www  GG63
8 kkk  5634
```